# Dreamhost DNS CNAMEs work at my house, not for anyone else

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, dreamhost

I have my domain BQQKSHELF.COM that I bought through Dreamhost. I set up a CNAME so that zach.bqqkshelf.com points to my app at zach.heroku.com.

The app at Heroku is working fine. Everyone can agree on that.

When I go to zach.bqqkshelf.com, everything seems to work okay too. When I ask my roommate to go to it, it works. When I go to it on my iTouch, it works.

When I IM my friends and ask them to go to zach.bqqkshelf.com, they get a time out error.

How is this possible?

Comment: I think this would be better answered on Serverfault since CNAMEs aren't really programming related

Comment: What IP are you getting when pinging zach.bqqkshelf.com? Is your hosts file clean from any previously set up redirections etc.?

Comment: Did you IM your friends straight after creating the CNAME or did you wait a few hours for the new CNAME to replicate out through the DNS system? (Unfortunately it can sometimes can take a day or two to completely replicate out.)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might have a caching issue.  Did you have a previous value for zach.bqqkshelf.com?  (I.E., did it used to point somewhere else?)

It can sometimes take a while (at least a day) for DNS changes to propagate, due to the distributed and highly cached nature of DNS.

Answer (score 0):

When I ping zach.bqqkshelf.com, I get:

```
PING heroku.com (75.101.145.87): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
Request timeout for icmp_seq 6
Request timeout for icmp_seq 7
```

I've flushed my DNS settings on Dreamhost, I'll see if that helps. In the meantime, is there a way to test without IMing my friends?

Also, where would this hosts file be?

Comment: You should post follow-ups as comments or edits to your question rather than as answers.

Answer (score 0):

RE: testing without IMing friends, you can use a DNS checker like [this one](http://www.squish.net/dnscheck/).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you're curious, this is almost certainly a problem that your friend on IM is behind a Micrsoft Server 2003 DNS server; I've tracked down the Dreamhost + CNAME issue to that on our end.